# Multiple filters in .RowFilter

Tags: .net, vb.net

I'm trying to combine some filters.

```
SearchString = "Col1 LIKE '%" & TextBox1.Text & "%' OR Col2 LIKE '%" & TextBox2.Text & "%' OR Col3 LIKE '%" & TextBox3.Text & "%'"
```

This above line works, but when I add other things like the below, the filter doesn't function properly. Anyone have any ideas?

```
SearchString = "Col1 LIKE '%" & TextBox1.Text & "%' OR Col2 LIKE '%" & TextBox2.Text & "%' OR Col3 LIKE '%" & TextBox3.Text & "%' AND Col3 = 1 AND Col3 = 'TestingString'"
```

And how I'm applying the RowFilter:

```
myDataView.RowFilter = SearchString
```

Comment: What do you mean by _the filter doesn't function properly_? Is there some kind of exception? If yes, then the error message would be important here. Otherwise, try to describe how the resulting data doesn't match your expectation -- _I expected this row to be filtered out and it wasn't_ or _I expected that row to be included and it wasn't_.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the `AND` operator has precedence in the [DataTable exoression syntax](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression(v=vs.110).aspx).

For the sake of simplicity, let's say the following

```
TextBox1.Text = "A"
TextBox2.Text = "B"
TextBox3.Text = "C"
```

so `SearchString` would contain the following string:

```
Col1 LIKE '%A%' OR Col2 LIKE '%B%' OR Col3 LIKE '%C%' AND Col3 = 1 AND Col3 = 'TestingString'
```

Because `AND` has precedence, the above is equivalent to the following:

```
Col1 LIKE '%A%' OR Col2 LIKE '%B%' OR (Col3 LIKE '%C%' AND Col3 = 1 AND Col3 = 'TestingString')
```

which means that in order to match on the third `OR` alone, `Col3` would have to:

- contain the `C` character, and
- be equal to 1, and
- be equal to `TestingString`

It is impossible to match the last two conditions, and the first two are only possible if the textbox contains the text `"1"`.

I suggest you use parentheses to specify which filter should take precedence.